# Change mouse pointer

Tags: windows-7, mouse

How do I change my mouse pointer?  I know how to do it on a Windows XP, but I don't see the same options on Windows 7.

It would be even better If I could use a picture for my mouse pointer, if its possible.

Comment: "Installing Mouse Pointers in Windows 7. " http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfzwqxfCIbc

Comment: F1 is the global key for help in Windows. It contains most usage instruction in a searchable form, right on your desktop. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually quite a bit simpler to do in Windows 7! Open the start menu, then type "pointer" into the search bar at the bottom and click on "Change how the mouse pointer looks". You can also access it via the control panel, but this is a much quicker way to get to it. I like to change the control panel from its default look so it's easier to get to everything - you can do this by changing "View By:" in the upper rightward portion of the window to "Large Icons" instead of "Category".

To customize your mouse pointer, with a custom image, you'll first need to get software that will convert image files into a .cur format, the one used for cursors. IrfanView can do this; you can [download it here](http://download.cnet.com/IrfanView/3000-2192_4-10021962.html?part=dl-IrfanView&subj=dl&tag=button), and their [website is here](http://www.irfanview.com/). Once you've downloaded it, you should be able to just open a file and hit "Save As..." and choose the .cur extension, though I'm not sure of the specifics of doing this. After you've saved the .cur file, click on which cursor type you would like to change (Normal, Busy, Resize, etc.) and hit the "Browse..." and choose the file that you saved. Hit apply and you should be good to go!